# Можно ли в Firebase считать данные без аутентификации?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Как можно считать данные из `firebase` без аутентификации? Приложение считывает бд и выводит на экран.

Comment: Не стоит задавать несколько вопросов в одном, задайте еще один.

Comment: а что такое *аунтификация*? превращение в тётку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкладка правила в консоле

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Задайте в [Правилах](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) (`Rules`)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {//узел
      ".read": true,//чтение свободное
      ".write": false  //запись нет
    }
  }
}
```